# How to Hide Header in Homepage in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to customise a laravel site. I want a different header layout for the homepage. Please how do I do that.

What I currently have is a master layout which include the header layout. What I need is something like this in this website www.jiji.ng as you can see, the homepage header layout is different from the rest of layout. I need a general header for the site but different header for the homepage.

Below is the Master.blade.php code

```
@section('header')
    @include('layouts.inc.header')
@show

@section('search')
@show
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a variety of ways of doing this.

You could check the [current route name](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#accessing-the-current-route). Give your home page route a name, then do:

```
@if(Route::currentRouteName() === 'home')
    @include('layouts.inc.header')
@endif
```

You could also have multiple layouts for your app, via [the `@extends` keyword](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade#extending-a-layout).

Your home page route might do:

```
@extends('layouts.home')
```

and the rest of the app would do:

```
@extends('layouts.app')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use @component and you can pass any view into it like this:
`@component('header')
@include('your_header')
@endcomponent`